# Google translating companies' names instead of transliterating

Tags: google-translate

I am making a multilingual app using Google Translation service. My app mainly consist of financial data.

In my app there is a part where I get list of stock name which all be part of translation. As the stock name is a brand in itself it needs to be transliterate instead of translation. Google is translating all the stocks name instead of transliterating. Before there was a dedicated API for transliteration but after deprecation of API I am unable to do it with Google translation service.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Google translation service translating brand name but I would like to transliterate it.